# Можно ли использовать Woocommerce Payment Method не на товарах?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, платежи

Всем привет, назрел вопрос. Есть woocommerce, а у него есть платёжка stipe и другие. Могу ли я их (эти платёжные системы) использовать на других страницах, не checkout, а скажем в какую угодно мне, встроить и произвести оплату чего-либо? Просто мне нужно оплачивать не только товары, а ещё несколько инвойсов.

Comment: Можно, но сложно. WooCommerce payment gateways тесно завязаны на WC, его хуки. Проще сделать ваш инвойс товаром

Comment: Да, спасибо за совет. Вы уже второй кто это предлагает. Что ж буду этим заниматься.